# Checking Authority without a Model Instance throws error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a policy defined in AuthServiceProvider and in blade file, I access it using @can and it throws following error.

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::$check
```

Unfortunately, googling this sentence doesn't report anything so looks like it's just me facing this issue.

I'm on Laravel 5.4.

### Policy Check in Blade File

```
@can("use-some-module", null)
    You have access
@elsecan
    You DO NOT have access
@endcan
```

### Policy Defined in AuthServiceProvider

```
Gate::define('use-some-module', function ($loggedInUser) {
    return <can access or not>
});
```

Comment: is get error if u remove the null parameter?

Comment: yes.I still get that error.